# Send user to a view controller from one that was made in code

Tags: swift

I have a view controller on the storyboard that I'm trying to send the user to (`TitleInfoVC`), but the view controller I'm trying to send the user from was created in code, in `TabBarVC`, which is being set as the `rootViewController` in the `SceneDelegate`.

When I try either of the attempts in the `DiscoverVC` I'm getting the following error:
`Attempt to present <x.TitleInfoVC: 0x12b417630> on <x.DiscoverVC: 0x12b411310> (from <xDiscoverVC: 0x12b411310>) whose view is not in the window hierarchy.`

How do I send the user to the `TitleInfoVC` when the `DiscoverVC` isn't in the storyboard?

SceneDelegate:

```
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    window = UIWindow(frame: windowScene.coordinateSpace.bounds)
    window?.windowScene = windowScene
    window?.rootViewController = TabBarVC()
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

TabBarVC:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let vc1 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: DiscoverVC())
    let vc2 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: SearchVC())
    
    vc1.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(systemName: "house")
    vc2.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
    
    vc1.title = "Discover"
    vc2.title = "Search"
    
    setViewControllers([vc1, vc2], animated: true)
}
```

DiscoverVC (Where I'm trying to send the user from) :

```
    func sendToView(titleID: Int) {
    let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let titleInfoVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TitleInfoVC") as! TitleInfoVC
    titleInfoVC.titleID = titleID
    self.present(titleInfoVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

    let titleInfoVC = TitleInfoVC()
    titleInfoVC.titleID = titleID
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(titleInfoVC, animated: true)
    self.present(titleInfoVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

TitleInfoVC (Where I'm trying to send the user to) :

```
    @IBOutlet weak var titleIDLabel: UILabel!

    var titleID = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        titleIDLabel.text = "Title ID \(titleID)"
    }
```

//EDIT:
Where `sendToView` is being called from (completely different view controller)

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedTitleID = titles[indexPath.row].id
    
    let discoverVC = DiscoverVC()
    discoverVC.sendToView(titleID: selectedTitleID)
}
```

Comment: Why would you both push and present the same view controller in the same command? And where's the part where `sendToView` is called?

Comment: @matt the push and present were to show what I've tried/both gave the same error, and I've updated my answer on where it's being called

Comment: How do you set discoverVC in searchVC ?

Comment: May you forgot : v2c.discoverVC = vc1 in TabBarVC.

Comment: @PtitXav, searchVC is completely empty, so I don't know what you meant by how do I set it?

Comment: In which VC do you call discoverVC.sendToView(titleID: selectedTitleID)
 ?

Comment: @PtitXav I call it in TableCellVC, I've updated my answer where I call it

Comment: This: `let discoverVC = DiscoverVC()`, creates a *new* view controller which has no connection to the current view hierarchy.  You need to use the existing view controller (possibly by sending it a notification).  Though, if you have some "completely different view controller" being presented, that's not going to be straightforward either.

Answer (score 0):

From what you show you need to work with a shared DiscoverVC.

in TabBarVC :

```
// use the share discoverVC
let vc1 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: DiscoverVC.shared)
```

in DiscoverVC declare the shared instance :

```
class DiscoverVC: UIViewController {
    static var shared = DiscoverVC()
```

in TableCellVC, use the shared instance

```
    let discoverVC = DiscoverVC.shared
    discoverVC.sendToView(titleID: selectedTitleID)
```